# Why can't I access a host port from my Docker container?

Tags: networking, docker

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) which asks the same question, but the solutions there don't seem to work.  Basically I'm trying to access a port on the host os from inside the docker, and I'm using the `--net="host"` flag as suggested in the linked post.  However, I'm still unable to access the port.  The only thing that works for me is to run my host web service on `0.0.0.0` and then access it from `192.168.###.###`, but that address changes based on what Wifi I'm on, so I don't want to do that.  Here's what I've tried:

Set up a test webserver that I can try to access from inside the container:

```
bash-3.2$ echo hi > index.html
bash-3.2$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1234 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 57942
```

Curl it from the host to make sure it's running:

```
bash-3.2$ curl localhost:1234
hi
```

Start up a container that has curl installed ([this is just ubuntu + curl](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/curl/~/dockerfile/)):

```
bash-3.2$ docker run --rm -it --net="host" tutum/curl bash
```

Try curling from inside the container:

```
root@moby:/# curl localhost:1234
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1234: Connection refused
```

I am on **macOS**, so I'm thinking it might have something to do with the container's host being *boot2docker* rather than my mac, but I still don't know how to mitigate this.

Any advice would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: I seem to have misread your question. I don't know how to do what you are trying to do, so I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I really appreciate the time you spent trying to help! :)

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing on Ubuntu 14.04 and it just worked. So you are right that it is very likely a `MAC` issue. I don't have any experience on `MAC`, so that is as far as I can help you.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Docker for `MAC`. See https://forums.docker.com/t/should-docker-run-net-host-work/14215/10 and https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/68